# Latex List of figures

Tags: table-of-contents

how can i remove the space before the list of figure title and change the color of the title. Please can anyone help me !
[image]

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your question.

Comment: i'm just adding the table of figures and tables : \newpage
\hypersetup{linkcolor = black}
\listoffigures
\newpage 
\listoftables
\newpage

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. (You can use the `edit` button to add more information to your question and the `{}` buttom to fromat the code.) That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: You really need to provide more information about your document setup. In particular, which document class do you employ? And, do you employ a package such as `tocloft` to help control the appearance of all elements of the table of contents, the list of figures, and the list of tables?